# How can I properly link my ui and server files for this Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to put together a Shiny app; this is far outside what I would normally be doing. Originally, I put together a function (`coolFunction` below) that takes three inputs:

1. `x` - A string
2. `y` - A string taken from a list
3. `t` - A number

and returns either a data frame or a list. The UI file seems to put everything together correctly:

```
# Required package for shiny apps
library(shiny)

# Possible responses for part of speech
ppos = c("one", "two", "three")



ui <- fluidPage(

# Title using HTML
h1("Cool Title Here", align = "center"),

# Put results in sidebar
sidebarPanel(
        h3("Results"),
        p("Descriptive words"),
        renderTable("finresult")
        ),

# Main panel for instructions and input
mainPanel(
# Sidebar for input
h3("Instructions", align = "center"),
p("Words here. Once you've entered all of the required information, click the \"go\" button to get your results."),

# Numbered list of instructions for input
tags$ol(

# Item 1
tags$li("Instructions for Point 1."),

# Input 1
textAreaInput("x", "Enter your string here:", rows = 3),

# Item 2
tags$li("Instructions for Point 2."),

# Input 2
sliderInput("t", "Indicate your desired number of results:", value = 10,
            min = 1, max = 50),

# Item 3
tags$li("Instructions for Point 3."),

# Input 3
selectInput("y", "Pick from list:", ppos)

# Close numbered list
)
# Close sidebar
),

# Action button to go
actionButton("button", label = "Do it!")

# Close fluidpage
)
```

but the server file doesn't seem to produce anything. Ideally, I'd like the user to hit the "go" button to make the script run and generate output each time.

```
shinyServer(
        function(input, output, session) {

        observeEvent(input$button,
        coolFunction(input$x, input$y, input$t),
        output$finresult <- renderTable(finresult)
        )
        })
```

I'm sure I've missed something fundamental. Does anyone see it?

Comment: OP you posted the same code twice.

Comment: @chemdork123 - Corrected. Thanks for that!

Comment: `finresult`? Where is this assigned?

Comment: @rbasa - `finresult` is the data table resulting from the `coolFunction` function. If this was just the function, the output would be given with a `paste()` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer. It is here:

```
shinyServer(
        function(input, output, session) {

        observeEvent(input$button,
        output$finresult <- renderTable({
                coolFunction(input$x, input$y, input$t)})
        )
        })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There you go. You were trying to render `finresult` but that was never defined beforehand.